# Multiple Functions in one onClick for one button

Tags: html, button

Is there a way to put two functions in one onClick in a button?

For example...

```
<button onClick="function1; function2;"> </button>
```

That ^ doesn't seem to work for me and that's all I've been told to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<button onClick="function;"> </button>
```

And then

```
function() {
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

Comment: Another question. How do you make a button disappear in a function?

Comment: Get the button through a DOM lookup and set the display off. Check w3shools or similar Javascript reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        function1();
        function2();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick="function1;"> </button>
```

Now in function1, call function2.

```
function1() {
   //Code for function1;
   function2();
}
```